# How to add children to accordion children in flex 4?

Tags: actionscript, flex4, accordion

I have spent hours trying to figure this out...any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

I have an ArrayCollection that is read to generate containers in an accordion programmatically:

```
    <s:ArrayCollection id="_ac_ps">
        <fx:Object label="Block and lot" data="_blocklot"  searchType="districtblocklot"  info="" />
        <fx:Object label="Address" data="_address" searchType="singletxtstring"  info=""/>
        <fx:Object label="Owner name" data="_owner" searchType="singletxtstring"  info=""/>
        <fx:Object label="Advanced data mining" data="_advanced" searchType="advancedmining"  info=""/>
    </s:ArrayCollection>
```

And this is how I generate the accordion children:

```
    for (var num1:int = 0; num1 <= _ac_ps.length - 1; num1++)
                    {
                        navContent = new NavigatorContent();
                        navContent.percentWidth = 100;
                        navContent.percentHeight = 100;
                        navContent.label = _ac_ps[num1].label;
                        navContent.id = ""+_ac_ps[num1].data;
                        navContent.name = ""+_ac_ps[num1].data;
                        ////(""+navContent.id);
                        _searchAccordion.addChild(navContent);
                    }
```

This works fine.  Now what I want to do is based on the id of the navigator contents in the accordion, add children.  For example, I want to add a child of type Label into the navigatorContent with the id of "_blocklot", but a textInput box into the navigatorContent object with an id of "_address".

```
    private function loadSearchControls( ):void
        {
            var accordionChildren:Array = _searchAccordion.getChildren();
            for each(var currentnavContent:NavigatorContent in accordionChildren)
            {
                Alert.show (""+currentnavContent.id, "currentnavContent.id");
                if (currentnavContent.id == "_blocklot")
                {

                    try{
                        var _label:Label = new Label();
                        _label.text = "come on now!!!!!!";
                        //SO HOW DO I CAPTURE THE ID SO THAT I CAN ADD THIS LABEL AS A CHILD???
                        //_searchAccordion._blocklot.addChild(_label);  does not work

                    }
                    catch(errorObj:Error)
                    {
                        Alert.show("nope");
                    }


                }
                else if (currentnavContent.id == "_address" )
                {
                    Alert.show("bbb");
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can also check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885478/loading-components-dynamically-in-flex-4/7896593#7896593

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.  You already have determined if the currentNavContent is the one you want, so just add the control to the currentNavContent.

```
        private function loadSearchControls(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var accordionChildren:Array = _searchAccordion.getChildren();
            for each(var currentnavContent:NavigatorContent in accordionChildren)
            {
                Alert.show (""+currentnavContent.id, "currentnavContent.id");
                if (currentnavContent.id == "_blocklot")
                {

                    try{
                        var _label:Label = new Label();
                        _label.text = "come on now!!!!!!";
                        //SO HOW DO I CAPTURE THE ID SO THAT I CAN ADD THIS LABEL AS A CHILD???
                        //_searchAccordion._blocklot.addChild(_label);  does not work
                        currentnavContent.addElement(_label);

                    }
                    catch(errorObj:Error)
                    {
                        Alert.show("nope");
                    }


                }
                else if (currentnavContent.id == "_address" )
                {
                    Alert.show("bbb");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Due to the complexity of the nested dynamic children, we bypassed this entire concept with accordions.